# How Can I Use Global Scope in Laravel Query Builder? (No Eloquent Model)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with too many mysql large views. I don't want to use Eloquent Model for the views.

I created "ViewBalance extends Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB". Everything worked as I wanted.

But i need to set **init()** method for company scope.

How can I use the global scope without **init()** method?

**ViewModel**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Views;

use App\Facades\CoreService;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ViewBalance extends DB
{
     const COMPANY_COLUMN = 'company_id';
     const TABLE = 'view_balances';

     public static function init()
     {
         return parent::table(self::COMPANY_COLUMN)
             ->where(self::COMPANY_COLUMN, CoreService::companyId());
     }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
<?php

$data = ViewBalance::init()->get(); // Worked!
```

Comment: I didn't get your question.. Can u explain what you really want to do?

Comment: Thank you your comment. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes like that in DB Query Builder. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question. Because, I don't want to edit my question for more complicate. I want to talk about a solution to this problem.

I added **$table_view** variable and **getView()** method in Laravel model. If you want, you can create trait for clean codes.

It can be accessed easily views. Also it is part of the main model.

For example;

**Laravel Basic Account Model**

```php
class Account extends Model {

    protected $table = 'accounts';

    protected $table_view = 'view_accounts';

    public function getView()
    {
        return \DB::table($this->table_view)->where('global_scope', 1);
    }

}
```

**Laravel Account Controller**

```php
class AccountController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $items = (new Account)->getView()->paginate(20);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('active', true);
}
```

or

```
public function scopeInactive($query)
{
    return $query->where('active', false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you your comment. But you wrote local scopes. NOT global scopes.

Comment: Please read my question title. There i wrote (No Eloquent Model). Eloquent Model different than DB query builder.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I'm struggling with Eloquent builders where I can't join to a relationship and get the sum myself.  Now looking into doing it with a Query Buider instead, but then I'm loosing my vital global scopes...

Comment: @DericLima Yes, i answered my own question.